# zoom is not working in webView on android application

Tags: android, webview

When I open pptx file through [this](https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/view.aspx?src=http://blessindia.in/bosch/assets/upload_data/topic_files/trade1/2fecb1f476991f6619cc81047b6f997c.pptx) link zoom is not working in android webview.

Here is the code that i'm using:

```
WebSettings setting = wView.getSettings();
setting.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
setting.setSupportZoom(true);
```

Answer (score 2):

In the OnCreate method, just put

```
webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```

And it's working fine here.

Comment: Is it working on tablet also? because it's working perfectly in mobile device but it is not working in tablet..

Comment: is your page has scrolls on tablet?

Comment: @AkashDubey there is no scroll in my tab

Answer (score 1):

For enable zoom option add this line of code.

```
webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
```